# pgAgent won't launch after a database restore

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, pgagent

I've installed `pgAgent` in our `PostgreSQL` database for scheduling our jobs, which really works like a charm!

However, after I restored a backup from our database in a test server, pgAgent simply won't launch. Interestingly enough, it seems that pgAgent ignores the current state of the data in this log tables and tries to populate them from zero.

See error message at the log file:

```
postgres@postgres ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pga_jobsteplog_pkey"
postgres@postgres DETAIL:  Key (jslid)=(1) already exists.
postgres@postgres STATEMENT: INSERT INTO pgagent.pga_jobsteplog(jslid, jsljlgid, jsljstid, jslstatus) SELECT 1, 25, 3, 'r'  FROM pgagent.pga_jobstep WHERE jstid=3
```

In case you're wondering how the backup is performed:

```
pg_dumpall --file "/media/jones/Daten/fulldump.sql" --host "address-to-my-server.de" --port "5432" --username "myuser" --no-password --database "mydb" --clean --if-exists --verbose
```

Environment:

```
Ubuntu 16.04
PostgreSQL 9.5
pgAgent 3.4.1-2
```

Any ideas how to make pgAgent come back to life?

Comment: You could backup data from pgagent schema, truncate tables, start pgagent, let it fill them with whatever it wants, truncate again and restore your backed up data. Not sure why it does that tho.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Truncating the tables would eventually do the trick, but the jobs history is also sort of important for us :-( I was hoping to find a less drastic solution. But you're right... if everything goes sough I won't have any other option. Thanks!

Comment: @JimJones can you see this question I have created the pgagent job can you tell me what is wrong in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45670622/how-to-run-a-job-created-via-pgagent-in-postgres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm definitely not happy with the solution, but so far I couldn't find anything better than the following options:

1. Truncating the log table does the trick, but deletes all job history you had (no big deal in most use cases):

```
TRUNCATE TABLE pgagent.pga_jobsteplog;
```

2. Alternatively, updating the sequences manually also works, e.g.:

```
SELECT SETVAL('pgagent.pga_exception_jexid_seq', max(jexid)) FROM pgagent.pga_exception;
SELECT SETVAL('pgagent.pga_job_jobid_seq', max(jobid)) FROM pgagent.pga_job;
SELECT SETVAL('pgagent.pga_jobclass_jclid_seq', max(jclid)) FROM pgagent.pga_jobclass;
SELECT SETVAL('pgagent.pga_joblog_jlgid_seq', max(jlgid)) FROM pgagent.pga_joblog;
SELECT SETVAL('pgagent.pga_jobstep_jstid_seq', max(jstid)) FROM pgagent.pga_jobstep;
SELECT SETVAL('pgagent.pga_jobsteplog_jslid_seq', max(jslid)) FROM pgagent.pga_jobsteplog;
SELECT SETVAL('pgagent.pga_schedule_jscid_seq', max(jscid)) FROM pgagent.pga_schedule;
```

If anyone has a more elegant solution, please let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody is still looking, I've found what works in this situation..

Log onto the database, install the pgagent extension
Do the pg_restore of the pgagent schema
Then restore the pgagent.pga_jobsteplog after the rest of the schema has restored.
Then reset the value of the sequences for each table to be 1 above the max value of the column the sequence is based on

Doing this, means you pgagent working, and you also have you job and jobstep logs.