# Paagent job doesn't run

Tags: postgresql, jobs, pgagent

In pgadmin (6.8) on MacBook, I right click a job, then choose "Run now" option, but nothing happened. Looks like the job is stopped.

**How to restart it?** much appreciated!

Comment: Make sure that the pgagent client is running: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45695881/2275388

Comment: Thanks Jim. I tried your steps, but nothing happened. How can I know if the pgagent client is running from pgadmin or terminal?

Comment: on linux (macos too?) something like `ps aux | grep pgagent`

Comment: I got this result: 131055  0.0  0.0 110512  2004 pts/0    S+   17:46   0:00 grep --color=auto pgagent, it's Interruptible sleep, right?

Comment: I believe it is not running at all. Remember, you have to start pgAgent it manually, e.g. `pgagent hostaddr=127.0.0.1 dbname=postgres user=postgres -s pgagent_log.log`. In some distros the client name may vary, e.g. `pgagent_10` in CentOS

Comment: I tried this command, nothing happened, no response/error, checked status and got this: postgres  5471  0.0  0.0 110520  2100 pts/1    S+   17:06   0:00 grep --color=auto pgagent

Comment: You might wanna check the log file. Perhaps there is something wrong with the parameters.